# Filter data.table by pattern matching

Tags: r, regex, data.table, grepl

I need to filter a data.table if the content of the column STRING match by pattern a huge vector of very long strings.
I can accomplish this as follow:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

DB <- paste(unlist(lapply(1:10000, function(x){stri_rand_strings(1, runif(1, 100, 2000), pattern = "[A-Z]")})), collapse = " ") #why paste? In this way grepl does not have to iterate through all elements of DB, but it stops as soon as it finds a match

dt <- data.table(STRING = unlist(lapply(1:100, function(x){paste(LETTERS[runif(1, 1, 20):runif(1, 1, 20)], collapse = "")})), NN = 1:100)

dt[dt[, .(TF = !any(grepl(STRING, DB, fixed = T))), by = NN]$TF, ]
```

Although it works, it is very slow. Given the size of my DB (~200k long strings) and dt (~80k rows), the ETA is more than a day.
Is there a way I can improve it?

Notes: DB does not contain duplicated, dt does contain duplicated strings in STRING

Comment: Have you tried to use: `dt[DB %like% STRING,]`? Is it slower than your solution?

Comment: If you have too many string to match, I'd create another data.table with key words, then use merge.

Comment: @zx8754, Indeed that would speed up things, unfortunately I still have >55k rows in dt when considering unique STRING